# Update Query issue in PHP

Tags: php

```
$id=mysql_real_escape_string($levelid);
        $l=mysql_real_escape_string($level);
        $levDes=mysql_real_escape_string($leveldescription );
        $sql="UPDATE `levels` SET level='$l',leveldescription='$levDes' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$result){throw new Exception(mysql_error());}
        $effectedRows=mysql_affected_rows();
        if(!$effectedRows){
            $sql="SELECT * FROM `levels` WHERE level='$l' AND id='$id' LIMIT 1";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);
            if(!$result){throw new Exception(mysql_error());}
            if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
                throw new Exception("Could not find Level's record in database to update.");
            }else{//no changes to the row 
                return "Level successfully updated in database although no changes were detected.";
            }//else
        }//if
        return "Level successfully updated in database.";
```

1. When i try to update, the level gets updated but not the leveldescription.
2. Also level is unique, but it does not throw error when i enter duplicate value.. though the DB is not getting affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seem to be fine, Have u checked whether $levDes have some values or not before query.
echo the query or $levDes.

Comment: Thanks i missed it in Flex... while dispatching